# MySQL %LIKE% problems

Tags: php, sql

My database is...

```
**Mytable**
UserID        Orders        Remarks
1         13,17,01,20,19    Done
2          12,18,17,15      Waiting
3                14         Done
4               15,10       Done
```

I want to display the UserID of the orders... example

1. $orders = 15,14 // SHOULD display 2,3,4
2. $orders = 15 // SHOULD display 2,4
3. $orders = 10,17 // SHOULD display 10,17
4. $orders = 17,10 // SHOULD display 10,17

however, with my sql statement, it displays the following

1. $orders = 15,14 // displays nothing
2. $orders = 15 // displays 2,4
3. $orders = 10,17 // displays nothing
4. $orders = 17,10 // displays nothing

my sql statement is

```
select UserID from MyTable where Orders like %$orders%
```

what am I missing??

Comment: The real problem is another poorly normalized database .. fix the core problem first. (If you really wish to keep the crummy design, see [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).)

Comment: You can't say `WHERE x LIKE %2,3,4%` and have it return every row which has any of those in. It will only return columns which contain the string "2,3,4"

Comment: You just found out why normalization is useful..

Comment: Isn't it better to start from the order and then obtain the userId starting from it?

Answer (score 1):

A 'LIKE' will search the string in that field for the given substring. So:

```
select UserID from MyTable where Orders like %$orders%
```

with

```
'Orders' = '13,17,01,20,19'
```

and

```
'$orders' = '13, 01'
```

will not match, it would match if these numbers were in the same order:

```
'Orders' = '13,01,17,20,19'
```

To make your query work, make it like this:

```
select UserID from MyTable where Orders like %$order1% AND Orders like %$order2% AND Orders like %$order3%
```

using one $orderx for each orderid you want to get matched.

An even better way to get this fixed, is normalize your database. Read about many-to-many relationships, and put your orders in a new table. This way you can have as many orders per userid as you want, and still select them with the same single query.

Comment: wow, thanks! i got the logic of many LIKEs. but will try this yet. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, you have to explode the $order string with comma and convert it into an array. and run a foreach like this

```
$order_array = explode(",", $order);
$like_array = array('0'); // Stop errors when $words is empty
foreach($order_array as $ord){
  $like_array[] = 'Orders LIKE %'.$ord.'%'
}

$sql = 'SELECT UserId FROM MyTable WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $like_array);
```

And execute $sql .

Hope this helps.

As people suggest in comments, it very good if you have a normalized database. You just save all the time. You can find a good tutorial here.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/relational-databases-for-dummies/

It would be a great start.

Comment: thanks for the idea. will try this also. never thought of exploding.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if you have some problem in it. :-)

Comment: @Sarah : Did you get what you wanted to achieve..??

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure can make problem in case if you need to find data of order 15 using LIKE, it will fetch data of 115, 150, 215 1511 and so on. So I suggest to change structure of your table.